# JPA/Hibernate: How to use INSERT JPQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, insert, jpql

This JPQL

```
em.createQuery("INSERT INTO Count (id, count) SELECT 1, ?").setParameter(1, id).executeUpdate();
```

throws

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found ')' near line 1, column 29 [INSERT INTO Count (id, count) SELECT 1, ?]
```

How should the query look like?

Does it matter that I use JPA API but HQL actually? JPQL doesn't support `INSERT`.

Using Hibernate 4.1.6 in JBoss AS 7.1.2.
Reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2637

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `count` is a reserved word, adding square brackets around it like  `[count]` will work.

Comment: You're probably right, but [] doesn't work and I can't find how to escape this keyword...

Comment: Well then that depends on the Database Provider.

Comment: I think it doesn't since it's object property, not column name. Created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619630/jpa-hibernate-ecaping-hql-keywords .