# JPA/Hibernate: Escaping HQL keywords

Tags: hibernate, jpa, escaping, hql

This is similar to [How to escape reserved words in Hibernate's HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql). But I use JPA, so the solution isn't applicable.

So, how can I escape HQL keywords in JPA?

Example query:  (`count` is the offending.)

```
em.createQuery("INSERT INTO Count (id, count) SELECT 1, ?").setParameter(1, id).executeUpdate();
```

There's this jira [HHH-3811](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3811), still open.
Not sure if relevant since it's about SQL keywords, not HQL keywords.

Comment: That's unfortunate table and column name :). Did you try the most popular escaping characters , eg. using backticks (``), quotes or double quotes around the column name? I'm afraid it will be provider specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
em.createQuery("INSERT INTO Count c (c.id, c.count) SELECT 1, ?").setParameter(1, id).executeUpdate();
```

That should make it clear to JPA that you mean properties, not keywords.